# Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null: but I can't spot the error

Tags: powershell

This is my code but i dont know what i need to supply:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content "C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Execute\Testing\servers.txt"
$ServerList

$Header="FolderPath,IdentityReference,AccessControlType,IsInherited,InheritedFlags,PropagationFlags"

Add-Content -Value $Header -Path $Output

Foreach  ($Server in $ServerList) {
    $output = "\\$server\C:\Users\munjanga\Desktop\Execute\Testing $server.output.csv"
    Del $Output -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    $RootPath ="\\$Server\C:\system.sav"

    $Folders = dir $RootPath -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true} -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    Add-Content -Value "$Header" -Path $Output

    Foreach ($Folder in $Folders){

        $ACLs = get-acl $Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object { $_.Access }

        Foreach ($ACL in $ACLs){

            $OutInfo = $Folder.Fullname + "," + $ACL.IdentityReference + "," + $ACL.AccessControlType + "," + $ACL.IsInherited + "," + $ACL.InheritanceFlags + "," + $ACL.PropagationFlags

            Add-Content -Value $OutInfo -Path $output -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: On what line? Is it the first call to `Add-Content? `$Output` does not appear to be set before that.

Comment: Yes thats the line its appearing on

Comment: It looks like you should just remove that line. There is already a line like it inside the loop.

Comment: If I remove that line, I get the comment, its not in red so i am assuming it's not an error just a requirement: "cmdlet Where-Object at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
FilterScript:"

Answer (score 0):

In line 4 you are invoking the Add-Content cmdlet, which requires a something to be passed to -Path, you are trying to use $Output, which is an empty (null) variable.

Assuming you are getting the warning on line 12 when calling Where-Object? It looks like you are trying to do a directory listing on a unc path that doesnt exist, getting nothing back to pipe to where. Is \$Server\C:\system.sav really supposed to be the admin share a la \$Server\C$\system.sav ?

Comment: So the unc path is possibly what's giving me the error? My issue is I can test in the actual servers yet as I don't have access but the unc path will be different ..so aside from that could the be any other problems with the code?